# .AppendChild() not displaying after the execution of the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Well, that's a strange problem, when the scripts run, it works well but it doesn't display it on screen and then when I "inspect element" and close the inspect element's window or zoom in/out the page, it shows up.
I'm sure that there is nothing wrong with any "display" css property, because it wouldn't display even after zooming in/out...

I really can't figure out why is this happening :/

Script:

```
function css() //create new
{
    var qntinputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var j = qntinputs.length + 9;
var i = qntinputs.length;


for (i; i<j;i++)
{ 
    table = document.getElementById("table");
      var element = document.createElement('div');
      var input = document.createElement("input");
      element.className = "cell";
      element.style.paddingTop = "0px";
      element.style.height = "50px";
      input.className = "insert" + i;
      if (i == j-1 || i == j-2)
      {
          if (i==j-1) 
          {
               element.style.width ="100px";
               input.style.width ="90px";
               input.style.paddingLeft = "5px";
          }
          else 
          {
              element.style.width ="90px";
              input.style.width ="90px";
          }
        input.type = "checkbox";
      }
      else
      {
          if (i == j-4 || i == j-3)
          {
              input.type = "time";
          }
          else
          {

              if (i== j-5)
              {
                input.type = "date";
              }
                  else
                  {
                      if (i== j-6)
                      {
                        element.style.width = "90px";
                        input.style.width = "80px";
                      }
              }
           }
      } 
      document.getElementById("table").appendChild(element);
     table.appendChild(element);
     element.appendChild(input);
}
i = qntinputs.length;
}
```

Is there a way to "refresh" or zoom in and out again to show it up?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `div` as a `table` child. It needs to be inside of a `td`. You need to append a `tr` to the table, then a `td` and then the `div` element, or instead of the `div` insert the content directly on the `td`

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't mention it, this ID "table" is a div, it's only a name for it. i'll edit and put the html.